# From an async.each send to two differents functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to do something like this, I receive information to an array of objects, then I use an async.each function, to call two functions that send the data to another api, I'm using ExpressJs. Here is the code:

The async function:

```
 async.each(readingsArray, function(reading, callback) {
    var firstTwo;
    firstTwo = reading.value.substring(0,2);
    if(firstTwo === '32') {
      updateLocation(reading, function() {
        callback();
      });
    } else {
      updateItem(reading, function() {
        callback();
      });
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(Boom.badRequest('Can't sent data'));
    } else {
      res.send({
        statusCode: 200,
        message: 'Data sent'
      });
    }
  });
```

And the other two functions:

```
    var updateLocation = function updateLocation (reading, callback) {
    request.patch(config.url + '/handhelds/' + reading.id)
    .send({
      //some information
    })
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    });
  };



  var updateItem = function updateItem(lectura, callback) {
  request.post(config.url + '/items/' + reading.id +    '/event')
  .send({
   //some information
  })
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
        callback();
      }
    });
};
```

I'm still trying to understand the asynchronous part of nodejs. What I'm trying to do is to update a device location, after that, send items with the other function updateItem until another updateLocation is call, then continue sending items. Thats why in the Async I put an if that identifies from a location or item. Is it possible?

**EDIT1:**

Here is all the code that I use:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('superagent');
var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var Boom = require('boom');

var config = require('./config.js');

var app = express();

var getReadings = function getReadings(csvValue, mac) {
//Here I return the array of objects

  var readings, values;

  var arrayFromCSV = function arrayFromCSV(csv) {

    var array = values.replace(/\n/g, ',').replace(/\'/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '').split(',');
    array.pop(); 
    return array;
  };

  var epochToISO = function epochToISO(epochValue) {

    var epochInMilliseconds = parseInt(epochValue, 10) / 1000;
    var date = new Date(epochInMilliseconds);
    return date.toISOString();
  };

  var convertToArgentinaTimezone = function convertToArgTimezone(utcTime) {

    return moment.tz(utcTime, 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires').format();
  };

  var separateValues = function separateValues(readings) {

    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lecturas.length; i += 4) {
      var newObject = {
        epc: lecturas[i + 1],
        mac: mac,
        timeStamp: convertToArgentinaTimezone(epochToISO(lecturas[i + 2]))
      };
      items.push(newObject);
    }
    return items;
  };

  lecturas = arrayFromCSV(valorCSV);
  epcs = separarPorEPC(lecturas);

  return epcs;
};

 var updateLocation = function updateLocation (reading, callback) {
    request.patch(config.url + '/handhelds/' + reading.id)
    .send({
      //some information
    })
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    });
  };

var updateItem = function updateItem(lectura, callback) {
  request.post(config.url + '/items/' + reading.id +    '/event')
  .send({
   //some information
  })
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
        callback();
      }
    });
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var readingsInValues = req.body.field_values;
  var mac = req.body.reader_name.replace(/\'/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '');
  var readingArrays = getReadings(readingsInValues, mac);
   async.each(readingsArrays, function(reading, callback) {
    var firstTwo;
    firstTwo = reading.value.substring(0,2);
    if(firstTwo === '32') {
      updateLocation(reading, function() {
        callback();
      });
    } else {
      updateItem(reading, function() {
        callback();
      });
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(Boom.badRequest('Can't sent data'));
    } else {
      res.send({
        statusCode: 200,
        message: 'Data sent'
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log('Traductor encendido');

app.listen(config.port);
```

The array looks like this:

```
      [ { id: '32144B5A1231200000001',
        mac: '00:16:25:10:57:E9',
        timeStamp: '2015-11-20T10:28:26-03:00' },
      { id: '30142F13F44123F0000057',
        mac: '00:16:25:10:57:E9',
        timeStamp: '2015-11-20T10:28:28-03:00' },
      { id: '32144B1231230000001AB',
        mac: '00:16:25:10:57:E9',
        timeStamp: '2015-11-20T10:29:09-03:00' },
      { id: '30142F13F0234234000055',
        mac: '00:16:25:10:57:E9',
        timeStamp: '2015-11-20T10:30:19-03:00' } ]
```

Hope this clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `readingsArray` might contain data like:

```
[
  '32_LocationA',
  '0000_someDataAboutLocationA',
  '0001_someDataAboutLocationA',
  '32_LocationB',
  '0002_someDataAboutLocationB',
  '0003_someDataAboutLocationB'
]
```

These are 6 independent messages, collected in some order.

What you should understand is that `async.each` will send ALL messages at the same time, without regard for the order.  Your `if` statement simply routes each message to a different URL (based on the `firstTwo` value).  I'll call this your `discriminatorFn`.

If you care about ORDER, you should preprocess the array by grouping messages that need to be in a certain order.  For example, you probably want to send the `32_LocationA` message before the `0000` and `0001` messages.  Same with `32_LocationB` and `0002` and `0003`.  Let's call these "batches".

A batch might simply be the sub-array of associated readings, so an array of batches is a 2D array, with each batch in the "right" order:

```
[
   // batch A:
   [ '32_LocationA', '0000...', '0001...' ],
   // batch B: 
   [ '32_LocationB', '0002...', '0003...' ]
]
```

For each batch, you might want to make sure the `updateLocation` is called first, but you probably don't care about which batch goes first (they can be sent at the same time).  This is a use case for `async.each` and `async.eachSeries`, e.g.:

```
async.each(batches, function(batch, callback) {
  async.eachSeries(batch, discriminatorFn, callback); 
}, function(err) { 
  // results
});
```

The `eachSeries` processes each reading in the `batch` array and waits for the iterator function (`discriminatorFn`) to call its `callback` parameter before calling with the next reading.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

```
// uses the `reduce` function to transform
// `p` is the accumulator, "previousValue"
// `c` is the current element of the array, "currentValue" 
var batched = readingsArray.reduce(function(p, c) {
  if(c.value.substring(0,2) == '32') { p.push([]); }
  p[p.length-1].push(c); 
  return p;
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your answer, you are right with the readingArray structure it's something like that, my question how can I separate the array in the sub arrays like you post?

Answer (score 0):

If `request` is from Express, it's not for what you're trying to do so this won't work. It's for hosting a server answering to client requests.

This will help you do http calls from your code: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback. Or you can use an existing package to simplify your code ([this for example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s-ajax))

Async doesn't guarantee any order for the processing of the readings, are you sure it's what you want?

Also you can simplify your code, `callback` is already a function so you don't need to wrap it inside a function.

```
async.each(readingsArray, function (reading, callback) {
  var firstTwo;
  firstTwo = reading.value.substring(0, 2);
  if (firstTwo === '32') {
    updateLocation(reading, callback);      // <<<<<<<<<< here
  } else {
    updateItem(reading, callback);          // <<<<<<<<<< here
  }
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(Boom.badRequest("Can't sent data"));
  } else {
    res.send({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'Data sent'
    });
  }
});

var updateLocation = function updateLocation(reading, callback) {
  request.patch(config.url + '/handhelds/' + reading.id)
    .send({
      //some information
    }).end(callback);                       // <<<<<<<<<< here
};



var updateItem = function updateItem(lectura, callback) {
  request.post(config.url + '/items/' + reading.id + '/event')
    .send({
      //some information
    }).end(callback);                      // <<<<<<<<<< here
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing he's using this rather popular `request` module: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: I saw that after posting but I don't see `send()` or `end()` methods in the doc, I'm still not sure about that `request` object.

Comment: Hi ShanShan, thansk for your answer, I edit my question and post all the code, to explain better my question.